# Specific kind of date conversion in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have looked through the site and cannot find a way to convert a date into a specific format that I need in order to properly read file names.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am trying to get from the standard date format

```
2013-06-01
```

to the date format of

```
06012013
```

My current attempt is

```
date <- as.Date("2013-06-01")
newdate <- paste(month(date),day(date),year(date))
```

But that leaves me with a date of

```
612013
```

How can I make sure that I keep the 0's in the new date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `format`

```
format(date, "%m%d%Y")
#[1] "06012013"
```

where

```
date <- as.Date("2013-06-01")
```